# Loading an ICC profile with Magick++

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++, color-profile, color-management

Here is my code:

```
Blob rgbBlob;
ifstream LoadFile;
Image profile_test("sRGB.icc");
profile_test.write(&rgbBlob);
jpg_src.profile("ICC",rgbBlob);
```

I'm trying to load an ICC file and resize but I can't. Instead, I'm getting this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Magick::WarningMissingDelegate'
  what():  Magick: DelegateLibrarySupportNotBuiltIn `5orig.jpg' (LCMS) @ warning
/profile.c/ProfileImage/5743
      1 [sig] scale_image 2052 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to scale_
image.exe.stackdump
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rebuild imagemagick with support for the correct libraries. In this case, you must rebuild with LCMS support.

([source](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14959))